# Portuguese version of StackOverflow don't show only unanswered

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, unanswered-questions

In the home of thw StackOverflow in Portuguese I clicked in "Sem resposta" (unanswered) and the page show lot's of questions with answers how do you can see in the image.

[image]

PS: the page is:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are, confusingly enough, two different versions of the *unanswered* page. Each has its own definition of "unanswered".

The page you're looking at lists questions *with no upvoted answers*:

[image]

Whereas [/questions?sort=unanswered](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) shows questions with literally zero answers posted in response.

Comment: ah, okay. But is very confusingly. Thanks